# unable to connect to port 3343 despite opening port

Tags: linux, iptables, port

Here is my iptables, i am unable to connect to a web application hosted on 3343 depite opening it, is there an error?

```
[root@ip-10-128-74-111 ~]# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:3343
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: you've probably already checked, but the service shows up in a `netstat -lnt`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you first try to add a logging rule just before the one you wrote; something like:

```
iptable -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3343 -j LOG;
```

this way you can monitor if the traffic is actually getting to your server; if the traffic is actually getting to your server, take a look at the outgoing packets; maybe packets reach your application, but they can't travel back because of routing tables or anything else; if you can confirm the incoming packets get to your application, try with:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --sport 3343 -j LOG
```

THis way you can monitor which kind of packets, if any at all, your application is sending out, and through which inteface.

Also, I assume you've no nat in place, so the iptables -t nat --list -n is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I am using amazon ec, and I needed to set the security group setting on top of this. Thank you all.